# Defining <img src = according to the end of the link

Tags: php, html

How do I set the `src=` of a `<img>` element, according to the end of my link?

Example 1:
Link:

```
http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/see-img.php?img=http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=325356456.png
```

`<img>` element in see-img.php file:

```
<img src="http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=325356456.png"/>
```

Example 2:

Link:

```
http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/see-img.php?img=http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=342424234.png
```

`<img>` element in see-img.php file:

```
<img src="http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=342424234.png"/>
```

I.E.: I want to know if there is any script that I can use in `see-img.php` do what I was demonstrating above file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

Try this:

```
<?php
    //$str = 'http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/see-img.php?img=http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=342424234.png';
    $str = 'http://www.endertec.com.br'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $src = str_replace('see-img.php?img=' , '' ,stristr($str , 'see-img.php?img='));
    echo '<img src="'.$src.'"/>';
?>
```

Comment: It worked, very good, exactly WHAT I wanted.
One more thing, how do I do to set the $str as current link?
It is this link is variable, it is the current page link.

Comment: Thank you for help, as you can see, the script works perfectly!
http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/see-img.php?img=http://www.endertec.com.br/hf/do.php?imgf=dsdsd.png

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could do this:

```
$img_url = isset($_POST['img']) ? $_POST['img'] : null;
$img_file = isset($_POST['imgf']) ? $_POST['imgf'] : null;
```

Then with that `$img_url` you can do this:

```
if (!empty($img_url) && !empty($img_file)) {
  echo '<img src="' . $img_url . '?imgf=' . $img_file . '"/>';
}
```

The idea is to get the URL values which are known as `post` values, assign them to a variable & then do a check where you `echo` the values into `<img src=` tags.

But that is the best that I can do based on the lack of detail in your question. But the concept is solid and should work in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a built in php function know as [sttrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), it will return an int with the position where the substring you need begins. Then a normal php substring will do the trick.